# Node unzip . How to make file name

Tags: javascript, node.js, unzip

Using [unzip module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip) by NPM:

When convert, the name of converted file would be `doc.xml`, since unzipped xml file.

Don't want the name `doc`, so did this:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs')
var unzip = require('unzip')

convert(process.argv[2], process.argv[3])

function convert(path, fileName) {
    fs.createReadStream(path)
        .pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: '/users/*****/desktop/templatexml/' + fileName + '.xml' }))
}
```

And ran this:

```
node /Users/*****/Desktop/converter/converter.js /Users/******/Desktop/template/103.zip 103
```

But the result will always be `"fileName.xml/doc.xml"`

`"fileName.xml"` appears as a directory name.

Want to change `doc` part.

And if possible, want to get the file name from original file path.

Inside process.argv[2] is like

`"/Users/*****/Desktop/template/fileName.zip"`

Want to get the fileName from here.

---

Thank you for comment, like this.
But didn't work.

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs')
var unzip = require('unzip')

convert(process.argv[2])

function convert(path) {
    fs.createReadStream(path)
        .pipe(unzip.Parse())
        .on('entry', function(entry) {
            var fileName = entry.path;
            var type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
            var size = entry.size;
            if (fileName === "this IS the file I'm looking for") {
                entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/users/*****/desktop/templatexml/'));
            } else {
                entry.autodrain();
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip')
  .pipe(unzip.Parse())
  .on('entry', function (entry) {
    var fileName = entry.path;
    var type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
    var size = entry.size;
    if (fileName === "this IS the file I'm looking for") {
      entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output/path'));
    } else {
      entry.autodrain();
    }
  });
```